# Python Pandas match exact pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to match a pattern with a column of a dataframe

```
pattern='pgk'
df = pd.DataFrame([['merged_pgk', 10], ['merged_Pgk', 3], ['merged_pgk_stim', 12], ['merged_Scp1', 5]], columns=['condition','count'])
```

I want the row where pattern is in the column condition.

```
df[df['condition'].str.lower().str.contains(pattern)]
```

I tried this but the problem here is that it will return pgk row (what I want) but I got also pgk_stim row (what I don't want)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `np.where` with `str.contains` and `case=False` to ignore the case.

and `$` to only match `pgk` at the end of a string.

```
df['check'] = np.where(df['condition'].str.contains('pgk$',case=False), True,False)

print(df)

         condition  count  check
0       merged_pgk     10   True
1       merged_Pgk      3   True
2  merged_pgk_stim     12  False
3      merged_Scp1      5  False
```

Comment: `df['condition'].str.contains('pgk$',case=False)` would suffice right? It will return a boolean. Dont think `np.where` is needed.

Comment: @Erfan agree,but unsure what OP wanted so thought i'd add in the flexibility of `np.where` if he wanted anything other than a bool.

Comment: Actually pgk$ is enough. Thank you

Comment: Also, this is more efficient, than checking using df['condition'].apply.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `endswith` function
`df[df['condition'].str.lower().str.endswith(pattern)]`